# OSL: Giving the texture method a color instead of string

Tags: rendering, node-editor, shaders, osl

Is there a way to give the OSL method

```
texture(string, float, float, ...)
```

a color input instead of the string which reads an image file?

Or is there any type of workaround?

Comment: The whole point of the texture() call is to read a color from an image texture, so the filename of that image texture needs to be specified. What are you trying to achieve, what would the color input be used for?

Comment: @brecht I am trying to get an Image Texture input into the script node(similar to sampler2D from GLSL). But I also need access to specific pixels of the texture, not just the one where the shader currently is.

Comment: That's not supported, the output of the Image Texture node is only a single color, not anything like a sampler2D.

Comment: @brecht Could you please copy you comments as an answer, then this one wouldn't appear no longer as unanswered. Thanks.